# vim slow on startup

Tags: python, vim, debian

I have recently experienced a significant slowdown on vim startup.  After doing some extensive profiling,I have determined that the slowdown is happening during the youcompleteme#Enable() function, and specifically, when it calls s:SetUpPython().  This one call takes 3/4 of the total startup time.  I have python compiled into vim (echom has('python') equals 1), and I have python 2.8 installed on the computer.

I have used youcompleteme for quite some time and it has not been a problem before.  I don't know if it's related or not, but I recently updated from debian wheezy to debian jessie.  Everything else about the upgrade has gone well, so I don't know what the connection is, but nothing else has changed and this problem has started.  Thans in advance for any help you can give me.

Comment: How slow is it, actually? :)

Comment: only a couple of seconds, but prior to the upgrade it was near instantaneous, and I haven't added any additional plugins or changed my vimrc in any way.

Comment: I find that YCM takes a long time to startup if it isn't cached. If its cached I haven't had a problem with the startup time.

Comment: I'm not familiar with YCM caching. How do you do that?

Comment: There is still an issue open:
https://github.com/Valloric/YouCompleteMe/issues/2085